# What is the best way to share networking layer between iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, node.js

What will be the best way to share codes of networking between iOS and android? Our server currently uses java but later some of our services will be based on node.

We particularly want to share a web service library (communicating with server, and maybe also do cache on this layer??) for our iOS and android apps. And we will build UIs in native way (Objective C/Java).

Comment: We have a RestFull backend. And my question is how to share code (like react native).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the restful web services support in your server. It should not be a problem because both iOS and android can easily consume them.

Some caching can also be done in the devices by setting the correct cache policy .

Please do let me know if you are looking something more specific.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I you have **RestFull** web service in your server you can use in IOS from **Alamofire** library and in android use **Retrofit** library . I use both of there because structure of both is as same .